# Component Router and children with routes on AngularJS v1

Tags: angularjs, angular2-routing

I am trying to create a Blog component (a component that will create the subpaths for pages/tags, etc) using the new angular router. On every component, the component template will be the same (only the path of the component changes) which will also show different data. The goal is to provided a standard blog component that can be shared on GitHub.

The key problem, is that the blog component template will only provide the prev/next buttons.

The blog template should be provided by the user (as every blog's structure is different...)

How can that be done with the new component router?

Route:

```
$routeConfig: [
    {path: '/blog/...', name: 'Blog', component: 'blog'}
 ]
```

Component:

```
  bindings:
    query       : '@'
    posts       : '='
    prevPage    : '&prev'
    nextPage    : '&next'
    pageSize    : '@'
    tags        : '@'
    currentPage : '@'
    opts        : '@'
```

Routes example as done with ui router:

```
.state 'blog',
  url: '/blog'
  templateUrl: '/app/blog/blog.html'
  data:
    pageSize: 3
    query: '/blog'
.state 'blog.paged',
  url: '/page/:page'
.state 'blog.filtered',
  url: '/tags/:tag'
.state 'blog.filtered.paged',
  url: '/page/:page'
```

Comment: why is angular v1 in the title / tags?

Comment: The app is in angular version 1.5, using the new Component Router (same syntax as angular 2). So the solution will probably be the same for both v1 and v2